# How to create wrapper over event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class someClassA
{
    Connector connector;

    public void SubscribeToEvent(IList<string> stockNames)
    {
        connector.OnEventReceived += SomeReceiverMethod;
    }

    private void SomeReceiverMethod(ReceivedData receivedData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(receivedData);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to get this received data in other class on subscribe

```
public class someClassB
{
   var classA = someClassA;
   someClassA.SomeSender += SomeReceiver;
}
```

How can I achieve that `SomeSender` from `someClassB`?

Comment: In `someClassA` declare `public Connector connector {get; private set}`. Then in `someClassB` subscribe to the event the same way you did in `someClassA`

Comment: @user246821 I dont want to expose entire connector.

Comment: The OP states: _What I want to do is to get this received data in other class_? If you have additional requirements add them as an update to your post.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Handle and raise events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways

1. Raise a new event:

```
private void SomeReceiverMethod(ReceivedData receivedData)
{
    DataReceived?.Invoke(this, receivedData);
}
public event EventHandler<ReceivedData> DataReceived;
```

2. [Forward the event registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)

```
// EventReceivedDelegate needs to be the same type as OnEventReceived 
public event EventReceivedDelegate EventReceived{
   add => connector.OnEventReceived += value;
   remove => connector.OnEventReceived -= value;
}
```

The former is more flexible since it allow you to do some processing of the data before raising the next event, as well as changing types etc. But it require a bit more code